# mate-terminal showing unwanted text when it starts

Tags: bash, startup, xterm, text

i'am on parrot OS, after a forced restart my mate-terminal begun showing text from bashrc every time it started, after a "clear" it goes away and the prompt is properly colored and everything is functional. i checked bashrc and there is nothing wrong with it. i don't know where did this came from.

here is the text shown :

```
\]\342\224\214\342\224\200\$([[ \$? != 0 ]] && echo \"[\[\]\342\234\227\[\]]\342\224\200\")[$(if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then
    echo '\[\]root\[\]@\[\]\h';
else
    echo '\[\]\u\[\]@\[\]\h';
fi)\[\]]\342\224\200[\[\]\w\[\]]
\[\]\342\224\224\342\224\200\342\224\200\342\225\274 \[\]\[\]\$\[\]" - Parrot Terminal\]\342\224\214\342\224\200\$([[ \$? != 0 ]] && echo \"[\[\]\342\234\227\[\]]\342\224\200\")[$(if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then
    echo '\[\]root\[\]@\[\]\h';
else
    echo '\[\]\u\[\]@\[\]\h';
fi)\[\]]\342\224\200[\[\]\w\[\]]
\[\]\342\224\224\342\224\200\342\224\200\342\225\274 \[\]\[\]\$\[\]" - Parrot Terminal┌─[nina@nin-machine]─[~]
└──╼ $
```

i don't know if it's relevant but it also started making a sound when it starts. the same sound as pressing backspace with nothing to delete :P

thanks for your help.

edit : bashrc :

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

export PATH=~/.local/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/sandbox/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/share/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH
# path to personal shell scripts
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
#[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1="\[\033[0;31m\]\342\224\214\342\224\200\$([[ \$? != 0 ]] && echo \"[\[\033[0;31m\]\342\234\227\[\033[0;37m\]]\342\224\200\")[$(if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then echo '\[\033[01;31m\]
root\[\033[01;33m\]@\[\033[01;96m\]\h'; else echo '\[\033[0;39m\]\u\[\033[01;33m\]@\[\033[01;96m\]\h'; fi)\[\033[0;31m\]]\342\224\200[\[\033[0;32m\]\w\[\033[0;31m\]]\n\[\033[0;31m\]\34
2\224\224\342\224\200\342\224\200\342\225\274 \[\033[0m\]\[\e[01;33m\]\\$\[\e[0m\]"
else
    PS1='┌──[\u@\h]─[\w]\n└──╼ \$ '
fi

# Set 'man' colors
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    man() {
    env \
    LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\e[01;31m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\e[01;31m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\e[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\e[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\e[01;44;33m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\e[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\e[01;32m' \
    man "$@"
    }
fi

unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\033[0;31m\]\342\224\214\342\224\200\$([[ \$? != 0 ]] && echo \"[\[\033[0;31m\]\342\234\227\[\033[0;37m\]]\342\224\200\")[$(if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then echo '\[\033[01;31m\]
root\[\033[01;33m\]@\[\033[01;96m\]\h'; else echo '\[\033[0;39m\]\u\[\033[01;33m\]@\[\033[01;96m\]\h'; fi)\[\033[0;31m\]]\342\224\200[\[\033[0;32m\]\w\[\033[0;31m\]]\n\[\033[0;31m\]\34
2\224\224\342\224\200\342\224\200\342\225\274 \[\033[0m\]\[\e[01;33m\]\\$\[\e[0m\]"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -lh'
alias la='ls -lha'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias em='emacs -nw'
alias dd='dd status=progress'
alias _='sudo'
alias _i='sudo -i'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Show your `.bashrc`, there clearly is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the first occurrence of `if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then`
and tell that code not to run.
Delete it, comment it, test for `= no`, whatever.
The symptom should disappear.

Having isolated the bug,
now come back and fix the quoting,
or perhaps simplify the logic.
It is currently a bit of a mess, as written.

---

You may find that `$ set | grep PS1`
is helpful for obtaining some correctly
quoted text that you can paste back into
an editor.